# Move to previous Fragment without reloading while click the back button from current fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

I have a two fragment. example FragmentOne and FragmentTwo. in my
    FragmentOne have map,markers and one layout. initially the layout state is 
    invisible. when i click the marker one layout is visible in the same
    fragment. when i click the layout the click event redirect to another 
    fragment name called FragmentTwo.

```
now i am in FragmentTwo. my FragmentTwo have a back Button. when i click a 
back button i need to move to FragmentOne. it is working fine. but the 
FragmentOne  shows only the map and marker. i can't able to see the layout.

i need to move from FragmentTwo to FragmentOne. without reloading   
FragmentOne.

 i Mean i need to see the Map,marker and layout in 
 FragmentOne while redirect from FragmentTwo.
 I am new from fragment side. so please help me. Thanks in advance.
 i need to move from FragmentTwo to FragmentOne. without reloading   
 FragmentOne.
 i Mean i need to see the Map,marker and the list item(popup) in my 
  FragmentOne while Transaction from FragmentTwo.

 I am new from fragment side. so please help me. Thanks in advance.

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// 
   I have a two fragment. example FragmentOne and FragmentTwo. in my
FragmentOne have map,markers and one layout. initially the layout state is 
invisible. when i click the marker one layout is visible in the same  
fragment. when i click the layout the click event redirect to another 
fragment name called FragmentTwo.

now i am in FragmentTwo. my FragmentTwo have a back Button. when i click a 
back button i need to move to FragmentOne. it is working fine. but the 
FragmentOne  shows only the map and marker. i can't able to see the layout.

i need to move from FragmentTwo to FragmentOne. without reloading   
FragmentOne.

 i Mean i need to see the Map,marker and layout in 
 FragmentOne while redirect from FragmentTwo.
 I am new from fragment side. so please help me. Thanks in advance.
 i need to move from FragmentTwo to FragmentOne. without reloading   
 FragmentOne.
 i Mean i need to see the Map,marker and the list item(popup) in my 
  FragmentOne while Transaction from FragmentTwo.

 I am new from fragment side. so please help me. Thanks in advance.





 i need to move from FragmentTwo to FragmentOne. without reloading   
 FragmentOne.

 i Mean i need to see the Map,marker and the list item(popup) in my 
  FragmentOne while Transaction from FragmentTwo.

 I am new from fragment side. so please help me. Thanks in advance.
```

Comment: You need to show your dialog `onResume()` after making global variable or you need to use `savedInstance` for that.

Answer (score 0):

Save the states in global variables or another persistent data and reload in `onResume()`.
In anytime the Android S.O. will need unload the Fragment 1, because is recomended do in this way.